# How to convert date ignoring ORA-01847 error day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I'm using the function `TO_DATE(datecolumn,'yyyymmdd' ) as DATE_REAL`

When performing my SQL request I'm getting these errors:

```
Exception in component tOracleInput_1
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01847: le jour du mois doit être compris entre 1 et le dernier jour du mois

ORA-01847: "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
```

Is there a way to ignore these errors and take the date as it is, even if the date of month is bigger then is valid for the month?

Comment: what are you planning to do? look for the 57th of march?

Comment: i'm working on DB that i know is not consistent , it was filled manulley and there was some errors on the date field ( there is wome record not coorect ) i'm trying to get these date from String to date as first apporach and then there will be a modification after the process is done) bu as first i need to get all these date even if there are not correct

Comment: I'd rather say that you first have to fix those invalid values, and then move on. Because, you know how it is - garbage in, garbage out. Even if you fix the current error, don't you worry - you'll soon enough hit another, and another, and another.

Comment: so is there something that can do to get string to date even the day is not correct? otherwise  can you sugest me aother approch

Comment: for example is there something to do like this, when this problem ocurs make the day as fixed values like '30'  ?

Comment: You could remove the first 2 characters and use 01 instead of them. You'd fix *57th of March*. But, as I said, manually entered values into a character data type columns is a *nightmare*. I'd suggest you to alter table, add a new DATE data type column, and solve errors by groups - different, but valid date formats (such as DD.MM.YYYY or YYYYMMDD) will easily be fixed. The remaining garbage? Well, you'll have to look at each case and fix it separately.

Comment: For the sake of all that is holy, don't store dates as plain strings. You gain nothing from it. You lose in data consistency, and you lose time fighting these errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to Oracle 12.2 and use the `default on conversion error` clause of [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html):

```
to_date(datecolumn default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmdd')
```

(You may need to nest that within `coalesce` or `case` expressions to reattempt the conversion when the date comes out null due to conversion errors.)

Or, write your own PL/SQL function that accepts a string and a format, like `to_date()` but with additional steps to handle invalid data, and use that in place of `to_date()`. (If on 12.1 or later, make it [`pragma udf`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/udf_pragma.htm)).

```
create or replace function to_date_safe(p_datestr varchar2) return date
as
    l_result date;

    invalid_day_for_month exception;
    pragma exception_init(invalid_day_for_month, -1847);
    pragma udf;
begin
    begin
        l_result := to_date(p_datestr,'YYYYMMDD');
    exception
        when invalid_day_for_month then
            l_result := last_day(to_date(substr(p_datestr,1,6),'YYYYMM'));
    end;

    return l_result;
end to_date_safe;
```

(Edit) From Oracle 12.1 you can define a PL/SQL function inline with the SQL query.

```
create table demo (datecolumn varchar2(8));

insert all
    into demo (datecolumn) values ('20180101')
    into demo (datecolumn) values ('20180399')
    into demo (datecolumn) values ('20180299')
select * from dual;

with function to_date_safe(p_datestr varchar2) return date
     as
         invalid_day_for_month exception;
         pragma exception_init(invalid_day_for_month, -1847);
         l_result date;
     begin
         begin
             l_result := to_date(p_datestr,'YYYYMMDD');
         exception
             when invalid_day_for_month then
                 l_result := last_day(to_date(substr(p_datestr,1,6),'YYYYMM'));
         end;

         return l_result;
     end;
select datecolumn
     , to_date_safe(datecolumn) as converted_date
from   demo
/

DATECOLUMN CONVERTED_DATE
---------- -------------
20180101   01-JAN-2018
20180399   31-MAR-2018
20180299   28-FEB-2018

3 rows selected.
```

Or, do the conversion in Java.

Comment: thank you for your help, her is my structure of fucntion but i'm afraid i'm not expert on plsql, can you help me on this. here is my function:
create or replace function updateDate(date varchar2) 
begin

    if (TO_DATE(date,'yyyymmdd' )) as DATE_REAL  /// works fine return  DATE_REAL
else
   substr(date, 1, 6) || '30' as DATE_REAL return  DATE_REAL
   
end;

Comment: What if it's February? e.g. `20180299` becomes `20180230` which is still invalid.

Comment: Added sample PL/SQL function. It only handles one exception type though, so you might need to extend it to handle more.

Comment: thank you so much fot your kind help , i added this function on my sql statment but i got compilation  errors

Comment: Rapport d'erreur -
ORA-06550: Ligne 3, colonne 14 :
PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'L_RESULT' doit être déclaré
ORA-06550: Ligne 3, colonne 14 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: Ligne 5, colonne 19 :
PLS-00201: l'identificateur 'INVALID_DAY_FOR_MONTH' doit être déclaré
ORA-06550: Ligne 2, colonne 10 :
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: Ligne 9, colonne 10 :
PLS-00372: L'instruction RETURN ne peut pas contenir d'expression dans une procédure.
ORA-06550: Ligne 9, colonne 10 :

Comment: Perhaps your version of Oracle doesn't support inline PL/SQL functions. Try creating the function separately as `create or replace function to_date_safe(...` etc and remove the declaration from the query.

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL Developer to test my query: the structure is like this
create or replace function........;// this is the definition and then the sql code SELCET ......
the eroor is Erreur (16,1) PLS-00103 : symbole "SELECT" recontré

Comment: i post the error as response to shpow you the structure

Comment: Create the function separately. In the example you gave it looked like SQL Developer tried to treat creating the function and running the query as a single statement. Probably it needs a `/` character between the two sections, or else run them in different windows.

Answer (score 2):

You could (as @William mentioned) write a function that attempts to convert the string to a date using the format model you're expecting it to be, and then handles whatever specific errors you expect to see. For your example issue, if you want an invalid day number to be treated as the last day of that month you could do:

```
create or replace function updateDate(p_date varchar2) return date as
  l_date date;
  e_bad_day exception;
  pragma exception_init (e_bad_day, -1847);
begin
  begin
    -- try to convert
    l_date := to_date(p_date,'yyyymmdd');
  exception
    when e_bad_day then
      -- ignore the supplied day value and get last day of month
      l_date := last_day(to_date(substr(p_date, 1, 6), 'yyyymm'));
  end;
  return l_date;
end;
/
```

The first `to_date()` is in a nested block. If that gets the specific exception -1847 then the exception handler tries to use just the first six characters of the string to a date - which gives you the first day of that month - and then uses the `last_day()` function to give you, well, the last day of that month.

Quick demo giving a few sample values via a CTE:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD';

with t (dt) as (
            select '20180218' from dual
  union all select '20160299' from dual
  union all select '20180299' from dual
  union all select '20160435' from dual
)
select dt, updateDate(dt)
from t;

DT       UPDATEDATE
-------- ----------
20180218 2018-02-18
20160299 2016-02-29
20180299 2018-02-28
20160435 2016-04-30
```

It won't handle any other errors, either from the first conversion attempt or from the second if something else is still wrong. Depending on how bad your data is you may need to handle other scenarios in a similar way.

---

Since you have no way of knowing what the original date was supposed to be, merely that whatever was entered wasn't valid, it may be safer to throw the date away completely and treat it as null rather than the last day of the month, but that comes down to how you want/need to work with the bad values.

And as already mentioned, you should not be storing dates as strings in the first place - if the data type was correct you wouldn't have these types of issues. Invalid values would have been caught and could have been corrected by the user at that point, instead of you having to try to guess what they might have meant.

Comment: Also a note: it's better to use this function once to fix the broken data, and then use simple `to_date` for reporting purposes, than to keep the broken data around and use the fixing function in every query.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - it would be even better to change the column data and then use this function once to set the actual date values; but assuming the data type can't be changed then yes, agreed *8-) If the column stays a string then you need to stop more bad data going into it too really.

Comment: my implication was that "fixing" the data does imply creating a column with proper datatype and moving all data over to there. So we actually totally agree here.

Comment: I see; your reference to `to_date()` confused me. (I guess you meant `to_char()`, which makes more sense in context anyway, re-reading your comment). I think everyone agrees storing it as a string is the real problem here *8-)

Comment: i post the error as response to shpow you the structure

Answer (score 1):

Just check how the Date format  is stored in the database and accordingly change your format.

eg : to_date(start_time,'dd-Mon-YYYY')

Comment: my dates format are like this String   =>  "yyyymmdd" inside the data base

Comment: for exemple how can i chnage this linge "20160435" to  "2016 / 04 / 30"

Comment: `substr(this_linge, 1, 6) || '30'`, but that will - I'm afraid - not be enough.

Comment: thank you for your help, it's seem sthis works fine but the modification will be appliead on all records , in fact i would like only to update the line when the date is nor coorect is this is possible ?

Comment: @Feres.o, Each one of these cases requires it's own analysis. For example, does date `2016-04-35` imply that it should be `2016-04-30` instead, thus losing 5 days, or it should be a `2016-05-05`, which uses a cumulation of dates, like some datetime libraries do (in PHP that's certainly a thing, several other places as well).

Comment: date 2016-04-35 simply that it should be 2016-04-30

Comment: i need somthing like this: when the day is not correct put it as "30" otherwise take the record as it is

Comment: @Feres.0 "put it as 30" will also produce invalid dates in February.

Answer (score 0):

select start_time, case when substr('2016-04-35',9,2) > to_char(last_day( to_date(substr('2016-04-35',6,2)  ||substr('2016-04-35',1,4),'mmyyyy')),'dd')then
to_date(substr('2016-04-35',9,2)-(substr('2016-04-35',9,2)-to_char(last_day( to_date(substr('2016-04-35',6,2)  ||substr('2016-04-35',1,4),'mmyyyy')),'dd'))
||substr('2016-04-35',6,2)  ||substr('2016-04-35',1,4) ,'ddmmyyyy')
else
to_Date(start_time)
end from table_name;